# Not able to generate response_type code for android sdk for facebook

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-android-sdk

Please help!

I am trying to genereate response_type=code from the android sdk, but i am not able to see any option to do that. I can do the same for the web browser using redirect urls, but not for the Facebook android sdk.
I need that code to authenticate the user at the server side. I am getting the token, but that token should be used on the frontend side only, I even checked the manual build flow, it involves the browser redirection, is there any way i can generate the response_type=code, using the android sdk.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can. Actually exchanging the code for a token, requires the app secret - which should not be exposed in client-side code. So I guess Facebook did not make that possible to begin with - that your use case is slightly different here, and you want to send the code to the server, is probably not a thing they anticipated / prepared the SDK for.

Comment: _"but that token should be used on the frontend side only"_ - why? Says who? For example for website applications, it is very common to send the token acquired on the client side, to the server (to then use it to request user details server-side, so that they can not be manipulated on the client-side, before being sent to the server.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.